# Button creates list half way up webpage, as well as where I want to create it

Tags: jquery, html, css

I implemented a button to append content to a webpage. It works fine, but it also creates duplicate information half way up the page. I have trawled through my HTML to find a reason why, but can't find anything.

What's going wrong?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#Wresults').click(function() {
    $('#content').append('<ul />');
    $('span[class="Name"]').each(function() {
      $('ul').append('<li>' + $(this).text() + '</li>');
    });
  });
});
```

```css
#womens_results {
  display: none
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1 id="ResultsTitle"> Run Results for October 28th </h1>
<input type='button' value='Womens Results' id='Wresults' />
<div id="textHolder">
  <section id="womens_results">
    <article>
      <span class="Name">Rachael Armstrong</span>
    </article>
    <article>
      <span class="Name">Christine Boyd</span>
    </article>
    <article>
      <span class="Name">Jane Jameson</span>
    </article>
  </section>
</div>
<div id="content">
</div>
```

Comment: any chance we can get a screenshot of the results?

Comment: My guess is that there's another `<ul>` somewhere on the page. Your code appends to *every* `<ul>`. For example, in your demo here, every time you click the button, a new `<ul>` is added, but the `<li>` elements are added to *every* `<ul>` on the page, including the newly added one.

Comment: Instead of `$('ul').append(...` use this selector: `$('#content ul:last-child').append`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must have a `ul` on the page, I've added a `ul` to the code you provided and can replicate the result:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#Wresults').click(function() {
    $('#content').append('<ul />');
    $('span[class="Name"]').each(function() {
      $('ul').append('<li>' + $(this).text() + '</li>');
    });
  });
});
```

```css
#womens_results {
  display: none
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1 id="ResultsTitle"> Run Results for October 28th </h1>
<input type='button' value='Womens Results' id='Wresults' />
<div id="textHolder">
  <section id="womens_results">
    <article>
      <span class="Name">Rachael Armstrong</span>
    </article>
    <article>
      <span class="Name">Christine Boyd</span>
    </article>
    <article>
      <span class="Name">Jane Jameson</span>
    </article>
  </section>
</div>
<ul><li>extra list</li></ul>
<div id="content">
</div>
```

I suggest you add the `ul` to a variable and then use this to append the li's to like so:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#Wresults').click(function() {
   var womansResultList= $('#content').append('<ul/>');
    $('span[class="Name"]').each(function() {
      womansResultList.append('<li>' + $(this).text() + '</li>');
    });
  });
});
```

```css
#womens_results {
  display: none
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1 id="ResultsTitle"> Run Results for October 28th </h1>
<input type='button' value='Womens Results' id='Wresults' />
<div id="textHolder">
  <section id="womens_results">
    <article>
      <span class="Name">Rachael Armstrong</span>
    </article>
    <article>
      <span class="Name">Christine Boyd</span>
    </article>
    <article>
      <span class="Name">Jane Jameson</span>
    </article>
  </section>
</div>
<ul><li>extra list</li></ul>
<div id="content">
</div>
```

Comment: Append element with the same ID every time the button is clicked? That doesn't seem like a good practice at all

Answer (score 0):

It's not really clear what you want to have happen.  What's going on is you are appending a UL each time you click.  Then you are adding the names to each UL.  If you want to add names just to the first UL you can use ul:first.  if you want to add the names just the first time you need to check if there are any ul's and then add if there aren't any.  See code below.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#Wresults').click(function() {
  
  if ($('#content ul').length == 0){
  
    $('#content').append('<ul >');
    $('span[class="Name"]').each(function() {
      $('ul:first').append('<li>' + $(this).text() + '</li>');
    });
    }
  });
});
```

```css
#womens_results {
  display: none
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1 id="ResultsTitle"> Run Results for October 28th </h1>
<input type='button' value='Womens Results' id='Wresults' />
<div id="textHolder">
  <section id="womens_results">
    <article>
      <span class="Name">Rachael Armstrong</span>
    </article>
    <article>
      <span class="Name">Christine Boyd</span>
    </article>
    <article>
      <span class="Name">Jane Jameson</span>
    </article>
  </section>
</div>
<div id="content">
</div>
```